# How to create a List like Facebook comment section in andorid

Tags: android, chat, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a chat application, I want to show chat messages with multiple view type like

- Media Files (Video, Audio, Photo)
- Documents (PDF, DOC, EXCEL)
- Likes... etc

also, implement **reply of a particular message** similar to Facebook chat section in android app. Please suggest me how to do this with **adapter delegate pattern** 
Here images for reference

[image: Image File]

Comment: It should be very easy if your backend designed properly(i.e content type, commentId and replyId) you can use to share these ids in different screens in order to get comment and reply. 
In Client side you can also get a type of content by there extensions, using these extensions you can define different viewType in Recyclerview Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'Comments' Table:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
postid INT(6) UNSIGNED,
comment VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
)
```

I use php for my code and i don't know but you can 'take id of the post' when you are clicking the comment button, and then showing all comments with same post id.